# Visual Studio 2017 Tools > Extensions and Updates failure

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image: The Error]

I am trying to [install the Xamarin update extension](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/extension-gallery/). When searching in the 'Online' tab of Extensions and Updates because the content type of the response message does not match the content type of the binding message.

However there is nothing in the search bar when the message appears and the message remains after I enter anything in the search.

Any advice would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the VS Installer I was able to repair my version of Visual Studio and the error no longer appeared.